# Hot Keys missaligned in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm using Swing to create a hot key for all the menus. For Save As menu item The 'A' should be  under lined instead of 'a' immediately following the S in Save as. I've used the following code to create hot keys for menuitems
"for Save As Menu: MenuItem.setMnemonic('a');"

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the `setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(...)` to provide a hint to the JVM for which letter should get the underline. You invoke this *after* calling `setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A)`

Please check out the API for more on this: [AbstractButton API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html)

Comment: Thank You sir . I just made some typing mistake that's why it didn't work as it should work..